# How to cast full Timestamp into Date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, casting

I am trying to cast 2 datetimetamps in Oracle and result is as expected 'dd-mmm-yyyy', 
but when I am substracting those 2 dates I am not getting rounded number of days between them, instead I have decimal places.

EXT_DATETIMESTAMP is in format: '25-SEP-19 01.35.39.000000000 PM +07:00'

I am using CAST(EXT_DATETIMESTAMP as date) for both columns and my result is like this:

```
DateA             DateB              DateA - DateB
25-Sep-2019       25-Sep-2019              0
25-Sep-2019       26-Sep-2019             -1.00084490740740740740740740740740740741
25-Sep-2019       27-Sep-2019             -2.00315972222222222222222222222222222222
```

What kind of casting should I use in this case to have expected result without decimals?

Thanks

Comment: Ude Datediff function..

Comment: @KiranPatil `DATEDIFF` is not a valid Oracle function.

Comment: which is database you have use?

Comment: @KiranPatil Look at the tags below the question, you'll see the [tag:oracle] tag.

Answer (score 3):

A `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components.

A `TIMESTAMP` data type always has the same components plus can have fractional seconds and time zone information.

So if you `CAST` from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE` all you are doing is discarding the fractional seconds and time zone information; you will still have the hours, minutes and seconds.

If you just want year/month/day components then don't use `CAST`; instead, use `TRUNC` which will return a `DATE` data type truncate back to midnight of the same day:

```sql
SELECT TimestampA,
       TimestampB,
       TRUNC( TimestampA ) - TRUNC( TimestampB ) AS days_difference
FROM   your_table
```

If you have time zone information then convert the values to a common time zone (typically UTC) and then truncate them:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( timestampA, timestampB ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-25 07:00:00.000000000 +07:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-09-27 03:00:00.000000000 +04:00' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TimestampA,
       TimestampB,
       TimestampA AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utcA,
       TimestampB AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utcB,
       TRUNC( TimestampA AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) - TRUNC( TimestampB AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) AS days_difference
FROM   your_table
```

outputs:

> ```
> TIMESTAMPA                     | TIMESTAMPB                     | UTCA                        | UTCB                        | DAYS_DIFFERENCE
> :----------------------------- | :----------------------------- | :-------------------------- | :-------------------------- | --------------:
> 2019-09-25T07:00:00.000 +07:00 | 2019-09-27T03:00:00.000 +04:00 | 2019-09-25T00:00:00.000 UTC | 2019-09-26T23:00:00.000 UTC |              -1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1fd9fe19f7efcafee33f8043639b32ab)*

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRUNC` on both sides of the difference:

```
SELECT
    DateA,
    DateB,
    TRUNC(DateA) - TRUNC(DateB) AS diff
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query...

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
       TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff
FROM   dual
```